# What does the "jQuery214085758228134363891 = 1509" mean in the watch pane in the debug window?

Tags: jquery, phpstorm, webstorm

I am new to webstorm. What does the "jQuery214085758228134363891 = 1509" mean in the watch pane in the debug window? Thanks.

jQuery214085758228134363891 = 1509

Please see the picture below

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9mcGqIc.jpg]

Comment: Looks like data stored on the element by [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), using hashed keys prefixed with `jQuery`, probably to avoid collisions with native or other 3rd-party library properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe thats the jQuery data object it stores your data on for each element.

```
$('#someid').data('somekey', 'somevalue')
```

Its jQuery + version + some random guid. Looks like youre using jQuery 2.1.4 (Thats the jQuery214 part you see). After that is some random guid. 1509 may be the size or perhaps some memory address. Not sure about that part. But data for an element is stored on the DOM element directly in jQuery.

If you inspect it further you can see all the events attached to that element, if there are any, any stored data you added or even stuff jquery added behind the scenes like the event data mentioned before.